# How to edit and open core.editor for git on windows 10?

Tags: git, android-studio, github, editor

For context I'm required to follow this tutorial (link below) and I'm trying to change the default editor. Just like the tutorial says at to do at 13:08 I typed in git config --global --edit and it didn't open the gitconfig window.
 Instead it says
"hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... error: cannot spawn open: No such file or directory
error: unable to start editor 'open'

Am I doing something wrong?

Tutorial I'm following: https://youtu.be/56knIGoCcMM

Comment: You have set your editor to be the command `open`, but your command interpreter cannot find this command. You will either need to install this editor named `open`, or choose some other command to run your editor. (I have not watched the video.)

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial assumes MacOS where `open` is a system command which opens an editor. Your error message implies that `open` is an unknown command and hence you most probably don't have a Mac.

To get out of this you have to remove that editor configuration first:

```
git config --global --unset core.editor
```

After that it depends which OS you have and what default editor is configured.